# why I get an error with wow.js in server

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, wow.js

I want to use `wow.js` in my project. On the local computer, it's ok.
But when I published the project to the server.I get an error following this screenshot. And the animation won't work.

What should I do ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What screenshot

Comment: I would assume it's probably just a simple matter of the file path to hit the wow.js file of the local file path versus the server file path. That's where I'd start.... Or at least share the error.

Comment: @JoshuaTerrill sorry.I use stackoverflow for the first time. You can see the screenshot now.

Comment: It's a little peculiar that you are referencing wow.js through wow/dist/wow.js. Are you using typescript? Or are you transpiling?

Comment: @ChrisW.  l use webpack to bundle my project. I think my path is right. I share my error. thank you.

Comment: Ah sorry I haven't gotten a chance to use react yet so I'm not competent to the errors. I'm sure you'll get sorted soon. :)

Comment: no. I use webpack+react.  In accordance with the method of online.so  I import wow from wow/dist/wow.js.

Comment: @JoshuaTerrill  I can't get it. my code and node version is identical. why it not works in server?

Comment: @ChrisW. thank you.

Comment: Can you edit in the code instead of the screenshot? And also, to the best of my knowledge, WOW isn't going to be globally available (you wont be able to use it in the console)

Comment: sure.   I do not use it in the console. I debugger then  I find error  with wow. WOW is not undefined in server. However,I can get  WOW  object.@Isaac